# All Headers get put into one column after CSV to Excel Conversion with Python?

Tags: python, excel, csv

So i'm having multiple CSVs which i combined using this script:

```
import os
import glob
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
#set working directory
os.chdir("Path to CSVs")

#find all csv files in the folder
#use glob pattern matching -> extension = 'csv'
#save result in list -> all_filenames
extension = 'csv'
all_filenames = [i for i in glob.glob('*.{}'.format(extension))]
#print(all_filenames)

#combine all files in the list
combined_csv = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f) for f in all_filenames ])
#export to csv
combined_csv.to_csv("mz_all.csv", index=False, encoding='utf-8-sig')
```

What i want to do is convert it into an xlsx file, what i already did BUT all of the headers from the csv get put into one column which looks like an absolute mess. The code for the conversion looks like this:

```
# Reading the csv file
df_new = pd.read_csv('mz_all.csv')

# saving xlsx file
GFG = pd.ExcelWriter('MZ_EXCEL.xlsx')
df_new.to_excel(GFG, index=False)

GFG.save()
```

Here's how the excel is looking atm, as you can see all headers got pushed into the first column but instead i just want it to be organized like it was in the csv
[image]

Comment: Does the csv file save properly? So when you load: df_new = pd.read_csv('mz_all.csv'), are the headers okay?

Comment: Yes everything looks like it should in the saved csv :)

Comment: I could not recreate your issue. Why don't you save it to_excel immediately instead of saving it to_csv first?

Comment: Because i have multiple csv's, which structure wise are always the same, just the data is different. So i thought i combine them first and than convert them into an excel. Is it a better option to more or less loop through all csvs and add them one by one?

Comment: No I meant after you do the concat, just save the combined_csv dataframe to excel immediately

Comment: Than i get an error and the file looks as messed up as if i did with my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to save it to Excel immediately like this?

```
import os
import glob
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
#set working directory
os.chdir("Path to CSVs")

#find all csv files in the folder
#use glob pattern matching -> extension = 'csv'
#save result in list -> all_filenames
extension = 'csv'
all_filenames = [i for i in glob.glob('*.{}'.format(extension))]
#print(all_filenames)

#combine all files in the list
combined_csv = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f, sep=';') for f in all_filenames ])

combined_csv.to_excel('MZ_EXCEL.xlsx', index=False)
```

Comment: I just tried it, but i get the same header problem as before :(

Comment: I just noticed that your delimiter is ';' and the pandas default delimiter is ','. So you need to add sep=';' to your read_csv code.